# Proposal: Adding reason for putting on hold on a question

Tags: feature-request, new-users

There are many newbies on the website, but they don't know how to frame it or the question is very obvious or it may be any other reason to get enough downvotes or the question being put on hold.

The people/users who vote for that should provide a good reason as to why they are doing so, because the OP must know where he/she went wrong. There are some users who show their superiority (based on reputation or the organisation they are working for) like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690322/task-performance-between-using-terminal-commands-and-programming-logic). It is [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690322/task-performance-between-using-terminal-commands-and-programming-logic) which is put on hold as too broad. The user Andy Turner (you can see him in the comments) is very rude. His comments (don't even make sense. There are some other comments which are helpful like [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690322/task-performance-between-using-terminal-commands-and-programming-logic?noredirect=1#comment62858275_37690322).

Just because they have enough reputation don't make them superior. There should be a column as to why the question is being put on hold, and it should be shown on the question page. There are some users who just put on hold, but the question really makes sense and really have great answers.

Comment: What is the feature request? Adding a reason for closure? Such as "*Too broad -- There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.*"?

Comment: soo... um... there is a huge yellow banner.. basically right below the question that says: "Put on hold as **too broad** by [...]: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs." ... Did you miss that?

Comment: Umm.  Dude, have you not even seen the big box with the close reason prominently displayed?  Obviously people do not even read what is already there, so why bother adding more stuff for them to not read? Edit: LOL this is why your questions get closed.  You write one thing in your question, but you actually meant another thing.  You have to ask your question correctly or it will be closed.  We do not have time to hold your hand.

Comment: @JK. "LOL this is why your questions get closed. You write one thing in your question, but you actually meant another thing". Which part?Don't just say your question is wrong. If you got time to write a comment stating that you are wrong then you can atleast provide where did I go wrong. It can help me in future not to post such questions. The 3 comments above my comment are same. You didn't comment anything different from them. You got time to tell someone wrong(which many people did) but very busy to tell where that person went wrong(which none of them did)?

Comment: If a close voter doesn't pick one of the predefined reasons, they can provide their own. But people will only do that when the question is so off topic that none of the reasons fit. Besides, a person can always just add a normal comment if they feel they need to say something more.

Comment: @H-H This post is good example why people avoid providing comments to downvotes/close votes: you were given good hints on improving the post and you call user "very rude" as gratitude. (Possibly there are a lot of deleted comments with name calling and the like, but only moderators can see those and hence I have to make my judgement on just 2 existing comments by Andy Turner).

Comment: The irony of this post is off the charts.

Answer (score 25):

> There should be a column as to why the question is being put on hold and it should be shown on the question page.

How about this?

[image]

(highlighting mine, for emphasis).

Comment: @Undo OMG! I just said that users must provide reason! Not the pre-defined reasons! Because none of the reasons are applicable to my question as you can see some suggestions for optimising in the comments.Why can't you guys(most probably with high reputation) wont even read the question properly?

Comment: @H-H You're asking three questions in that one 'question', one of them too broad on its own. The closure is justified.

Comment: @H-H because that would be too much of a waste of time? The reasons are the distiled wisdom of several interaction of trying to catch the fundamental problems that makes questions unsuitable for the site. This reason, along with the others fit pretty well for almost all of them (say 99.9999999%).

Comment: @H-H just to be clear on this: you said "users must provide reason". We read it. *The users provided a reason*. You didn't say anything about *custom* reasons. Don't accuse others of not reading your question properly if *you* are the one who fails to formulate their feature-request in a comprehensible way (hence [my first comment on your question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325703/proposal-adding-reason-for-putting-on-hold-on-a-question#comment354705_325703)).

Comment: @Undo "one of them too broad on its own. The closure is justified". Which one? Thats what i'm telling. If they can provide a reason we(newbies) can improve for further question. Because some may not understand whats the problem( sadly, i'm one of them) with question.

Comment: @H-H "Does it depend on programming language also" is very broad. Fact is, your question is one of ~10,000 that will be asked today, and a good portion of those will be closed. We can't afford to be making people write custom reasons for *every single one*.

Comment: @H-H Additionally, you *almost* found the correct route to learn more about why a question was closed. Asking a meta question will get you sane advice about what you did wrong and how to do it better... unless you run in calling people rude and saying they think they're "superior". That's not a good way to win friends and influence people.

Comment: @Undo Thanks. What you said is right. But do you think the comment I mentioned in my question is right? This is a learning site. If a person wants to help, he/she may help but giving sarcastic answers which doesn't help anyone in any way is not acceptable(I think). I thought raising a voice against such "users" may help the site and the people very much in the future. P.S I mentioned only some "users" as rude (Sorry if I mentioned it in a wrong way previously).

Comment: @H-H "This is a learning site." Ugh... no. We are building a repository of practical, programming questions. Not to teach you something. You learn something in the process, but it's not our *reason de etre* to feed it to you.

Comment: @Braiam "We are building a repository of practical, programming questions. "    Which helps to learn.Right?

Comment: @H-H No. The fact that people might learn along the way is a fortunate by-product. If the aim was to help you write your homework (with admittedly a lot of exaggeration for rhetoric value; don't take it personally), we wouldn't have so strict quality guidelines to begin with. Lots of basic learning questions ("how best do this?", "what is the reason for that?") are blatantly off-topic on Stack Overflow. We *could* help a lot learning two things: solving your own problems and debugging. But experience shows that this isn't going so well either.